# algorithm to compute the largest subset of L in which every pair of segments intersects

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic, geometry

I came across this question in preparation for the final exam, and I could not find the recursive formula although I saw similar questions.
I will thank you for any help!

the problem is:
Suppose we are given a set L of n line segments in the plane, where the endpoints
of each segment lie on the unit circle x
2 + y
2 = 1, and all 2n endpoints are
distinct. Describe and analyze an algorithm to compute the largest subset of L in
which **every pair** of segments intersects

The solution needs to be an algorithm in dynamic programming approach (based on recursive formula)

Comment: What have you tried? This site generally isn't meant for solving homework questions

Comment: [Clique?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory))

Comment: @jontro I understood that if between two points a,b there is a line, if for two lines  (a,b), (c,d) : d<a<c<b so the segments intersects, but I can't figure out the recursion formula

Comment: What is the input data format?

Comment: Could it be, that 3 different segments intersect at a single point?

Comment: Hint:  Give each line a letter.  Move around the circle.  You're looking for the longest subsequence of letters that repeats twice each time around (from any starting point)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the question ("the **largest** subset of L...") is dealing with the subset **size**, and not that the subset cannot be extended. If the latter is true, the problem is trivial and the simple greedy algorithm works.

Now to your question. Following Matt Timmermans' hint (can you prove it?) this can be viewed as the [longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), except that we don't know what the 2 input strings are = where the splitting point between the 2 sequence occurences is.

[Longest common subsequence problem can be solved in `O(m*n)` time and linear memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). By moving the splitting point along your `2n`-length array you will create `2n` instances of the LCS problem each of which can be solved in `O(n^2)` time, which yields the total time complexity of `O(n^3)`.

Your problem is known as the maximum [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) problem (with line segments corresponding to graph nodes, and line segments intersections corresponding to graph edges) of a [circle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_graph) and has been shown in 2010 to have a solution with `O(n^2*log(n))` time complexity.

Please note that the maximum clique problem (the decision version) is NP-hard (NP-complete, to be exact) in the case of an arbitrary graph.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that Longest Subsequence solution; Maybe through the wiki circle graph example?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I appreciate it very much
I would be happy if you could elaborate a little on the idea of the Longest Subsequence solution?

Comment: First you need to understand Matt Timmermans' hint, which is easy and left as an excercise to the reader. Then what you have is a string of letters, in which you want to find the longest subsequence occuring exactly twice, and such that the first occurence is strictly before the second occurence (ie. the 2 occurences do not interleave). This you can solve by splitting the string at arbitrary points into prefix+suffix and running the LCS algorithm on the 2 parts. The winning split + LCS result is the subset in question.